# Where to place update core data function (swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, setvalue

I've done some research on how update core data and I've found the setValue() function.

I'm now struggling on where to call this function. Obviously I would call it when the data is changed:

```
if (textField.text != detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description {
        detail?.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "name")
    }
```

Where would I place this?
I doubt that it belongs in viewDidLoad and configureView.
This is for my detailViewController file.

textField is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell
    let textField: UITextField = cell.textField
    let detail = self.detailItem
    
    textField.text = detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description
    return cell
}
```

---

## Solved

textFieldDidEndEditing() solved the problem of checking if the value is changed and saves it.

Passing a textField that is a subclass of UITableViewCell is solved here: [How to call textField that is a inside of UITableViewCell (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346771/how-to-call-textfield-that-is-a-inside-of-uitableviewcell-swift-solved)

Comment: Do you want to setvalue when value changed to textFeild?

Comment: I want to setValue when the value in textField is changed.

textField currently holds valueForKey().

Comment: so try delegate method of UItextField   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        <#code#>
    }

Comment: Not directly related but `setValue:forKey / valueForKey` is outdated in times of generic `NSManagedObject` types. Use a subclass and dot notation. And don't forget to save the context to apply the changes.

Comment: Normally I think this would work, however textField = cell.textField. I've updated the question to include what textField is.

Comment: I figured out how to pass a textField of subclass UITableViewCell. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        txtName.delegate = self
    }

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("Tells the delegate that editing ends for specific textfield")

if (textField.text != detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description {
        detail?.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "name")
    }
    }
}
```

Hope This will be helpful..