# How to call textField that is a inside of UITableViewCell (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, subclass, textfield

I have a `UITextField` that is inside of `UITableViewCell`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell
    let textField: UITextField = cell.textField
    let detail = self.detailItem
    
    textField.text = detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description + detail!.valueForKey("number")!.description
    print()
    return cell
}
```

How can pass that same textField to:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("executed")
    
    let detail = self.detailItem
    let textField: UITextField = self.text.textField
    if (textField.text != detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description + detail!.valueForKey("number")!.description) {
        detail?.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

---

## Solved

I needed to add `textField.delegate = self` after its definition.

I assume it connects the view to the view controller, allowing it to see the `textFieldDidStopEditing` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give UITextFieldDelegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method itself

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell
    let textField: UITextField = cell.textField

    textField.delegate = self

    let detail = self.detailItem

    textField.text = detail!.valueForKey("name")!.description + detail!.valueForKey("number")!.description

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I assume delegate connects the view to the view controller allowing it to see the textFieldDidEndEditing function.